# Needing help with convex analysis

Tags: convex-analysis

If $f$ is a closed proper convex function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove that the function $\varphi$ defined by $\varphi(\lambda)=f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)$, where $x \in \text{dom}f, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex function as well. I've tried proving it by brute calculation but it didn't work out well. Any ideas?

Comment: But then $\;\phi\;$ is defined for **fixed** $\;x,y\in\text{Dom}\,f\;??$

Comment: Yes, x and y are supposed to be $\mathbb{fixed}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

\begin{align}
\varphi(\alpha \lambda_1 + (1-\alpha)\lambda_2)&=f((x+(\alpha \lambda_1 + (1-\alpha)\lambda_2)(y-x)))\\
&=f(\alpha (x+\lambda_1(y-x))+(1-\alpha)(x+\lambda_2(y-x))) \\
&\leq \alpha f(x+\lambda_1(y-x))+(1-\alpha)f(x+\lambda_2(y-x))\\
&=\alpha \varphi(\lambda_1)+(1-\alpha)\varphi(\lambda_2)
\end{align}

Comment: Small detail to add: if $a\lambda_1 + (1-a)\lambda_2$ is a convex combination and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ then $(1-(a\lambda_1 + (1-a)\lambda_2))x + (a\lambda_1 + (1-a)\lambda_2)y$ is a convex combination of x and y.